# Putting multiple spaces in ng-bind

Tags: html, angularjs

How do I put multiple spaces or tabs in the text for `ng-bind`?
When rendered on HTML, it just shows one space.

I have tried `\t` and `&nbsp;` as well, but no luck.

I need to show a `marquee` with multiple values on it. So I'm putting all of them in a string and need some more space between.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="firstName='John';lastName='Doe'">

<p>The full name is: {{ firstName + "    " + lastName }}</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** This code is just an example, I have many values that I'm getting from API.

Comment: can you separate your variables : `{{firstName}}   &nbsp;  {{lastName}}` ?

Comment: @31piy I have mentioned I tried that, and it didn't work. It printed `&nbsp;`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I have too many values, that are coming in dynamically. This is just an example to simulate my issue.

Comment: would it be possible to show an example of such data?

Comment: Its a complex nested json data, I'm iterating through it, concatenating all the values in a single string.

Comment: is it possible to collect them into an array (by flattening your JSON) and `.join()` them with spaces?

Comment: I already have spaces in them. The problem is when I use `ng-bind` or `{{}}`, those spaces are removed

Comment: the tag `<pre>` preserves spaces, wrap your code with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my controller, I put multiple `&nbsp` between the values.
Then I put `div` in the string.

```
$scope.values = "<div>"+values + "</div>"
```

In my HTML, I used

```
ng-bing-html
```

Because of this, the HTML was sanitized and added to the document as a part of HTML rather than string.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a space variable which holds `&nbsp;`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-init="firstName='John';lastName='Doe'; space='&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;'">

    <p>The full name is: {{ firstName }} {{space}} {{lastName }}</p>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: The code is just an example to simulate my issue. I have too many values, computed dynamically.

Comment: I have too many values, I cannot put them hardcoded in HTML like that. Thats why I need to generate a single string in my controller and then use it here.

Comment: @DushyantBangal but the space variable will be attached to the scope so you can use it in the controller and in the view

Comment: I cannot put `{{space}}` between each of them, because, like I said, there are too many variables and I cannot hardcode them to HTML. There can be hundreds of values. I am generating the string in my controller

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for doing this would be:

```
<p ng-bind="'The full name is: '+(firstName)+'   '+(lastName)"></p>
```

You use single quotes to indicate it's a literal and parenthesis to indicate it's a variable, then you concatenate using plus sign.

Why using attribute 'ng-bind' and not curly braces expression {{}} ?
By using ng-bing, you avoid the expression {{something}} to show up, if the DOM takes long to compile.